# sql server 2000 dts package fails when scheduled

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2000, dts

I have a SQL Server 2000 dts package which copies data from a DBF file to SQL Table
I have created a System DSN and provided UNC Names for both Connection and Database file itself.
It runs smoothly when ran manually but fails when scheduled as a job?
I googled and found that it has to do with the permissions of SQL Server Agent etc
Can anyone guide me to the right source/post a solution?
"The error says xyz.dbf doesn't exist" in the job history

This is related but separate question
If i am pulling data from one SQL server to another using dts package provided a condition only,For example ,copy the data between the servers if SourceServer table has a value "OK"
i.e if SourceServer.SourceDB.Dbo.CheckStatusTable.Statuscolumn="OK" then copy the value else do not copy
If I have something like above condition how do i embed this into a dts package?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hey - I'll answer the first question in your post regarding the error you are receiving.  When you run a DTS package manually, it runs under your context using your permissions.  When run as a scheduled job, the package runs under the context of the job agent, in this case SQL Server agent.

It appears that the agent is lacking permissions that you have in attempting to complete the operation.  Since the error is mentioning the DBF file, I'd start there.  Check any permissions for the file itself or whether the context is being passed properly.